# Is there a way to define CNN/Keras receptive fields that are content dependent

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

**Background**:

I have two-dimensional input data for a regression problem, which is not an image but can be represented in a 10x10 matrix. I know that prediction-relevant features can only emerge among certain matrix cells, which depend on the values in the matrix itself. So instead of using, for example example, 5x5 subsets as receptive fields for the Conv Layer, I want to define a filter that makes use of that knowledge and use a different shape for the receptive field differently.

Standard, square receptive fields assume that relevant features emerge in pixels/cells that are at most X rows/columns away from the pixel under consideration. So, to filter features around cell (3,3) this subset is selected:

[image: square receptive field]

In my application I know that relevant features around (3,3) emerge among cells that are in rows [columns] that have value 1 in column [row] 3, i.e. the receptive field that matters is:

[image: content dependent receptive field]
resultig subset is:  [image: content-dependent receptive field]

I.e. I first look for rows that have a 1 at (.,3) and then for columns that have a one at (3,.) and compose those into a new matrix. For simplicity assume that this always gives me 5x5 matrix.

The code for selecting this subset is easy:

```
from numpy import array
Tfull = array([ [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                [0, 1, 0, 1, 0 ,0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 ,0],
                [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]])
Trf = Tfull[[j for j in range(0,10) if Tfull[j,2]==1 or j==2]][...,[i for i in range(0,10) if Tfull[2,i]==1 or i==2]]
```

**What I Need**:

I want to define a layer in Keras (e.g., following this [explanation](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/)), that behaves like a standard Conv Layer, but instead of applying the same filter to each possible 5x5 subset, it should apply a the same filter to each subset selected by the rule above:

```
class MyLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        ...
    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', 
                                  shape=(input_shape[1], self.output_dim),
                                  initializer='uniform',
                                  trainable=True)
        super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end
    def call(self, x):
        ...
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        ...
```

(code copied from above link)

How can incorporate my definition of a receptive field to have a Conv Layer that uses this content-dependent receptive field instead of an NxN subset of the input data?

Comment: I think you can assume that `x` in `call()` is `Tfull` and the `call()` return something like `Trf`. But I don't understand what you really want to do. What the output look like when you really make it to use. From your example, if you change the (3, 3) to somewhere else the output shape will difference, and this will be the problem.

Comment: Yeah, your last point is valid and due to the fact that my example is shitty. In my actual (more complex) application the output will always have the same dimension. So you're saying that call gets passed the full matrix? Do a "normal" cnn would use this part of the code to select the receptive field?

Comment: Yes `call(self, x)` pass a metrix(sometime called Tensor) from previous as x, process it and then return something to next layer, but a real Convolution layer do that in c++.

Comment: You can just write the operations in `call()` and return the result to another layer, the real different from builtin Conv is doing loops in python may slower than those in c++.

Comment: Ok, for the speed I could define an external function. But each loop iteration will result in a new receptive field, how do I return the NxN fields? If you could point me to a resource where a standard CNN is implemented using a Keras layer I guess we can figure this out ourselves

Comment: Is this one OK, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.13/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/convolutional.py

Comment: Line 194 or 797 might look like that, it actually send to this file https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.13/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py but I never try more than this.